# How to assign value to ng-model definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ui-bootstrap for typeahead in my application.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newItem.id" class="form-control">
<pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" typeahead="asset as asset.asset_name for asset in assets | filter:{asset_name:$viewValue}" class="form-control">
```

When I select the autocompleted value, I can see my objects printed. But the problem is I am using `newItem` object to set form values and passing to `$http` requests, So how can I set `customSelected.id` to `newItem.id` ?

Getting error when I use something like this,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newItem.id=customSelected.id" class="form-control">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ue6jN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the selected `asset` `id` to `newItem.id`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newItem.id" typeahead="asset.id as asset.asset_name for asset in assets | filter:{asset_name:$viewValue}" class="form-control">
```

UPDATE ([**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ew43W/))

View:

```html
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.id" class="form-control" />

    <input 
      type="text" 
      ng-model="customSelected" 
      typeahead="asset as asset.asset_name for asset in assets | filter:{asset_name:$viewValue}" 
      class="form-control" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Ctrl:

```js
function ctrl($scope){

  $scope.newItem = {};

  $scope.assets = [
    {
      "id":"1",
      "asset_reg_no":"AST1",
      "asset_name":"Omega Shopping Complex"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "asset_reg_no":"AST2",
      "asset_name":"Keedam Chicken Farm"
    }
  ];

  $scope.$watch('customSelected', function(asset, oldAsset){
    if(!asset && !oldAsset){
      return;
    }
    if(oldAsset && !asset){
      delete $scope.newItem.id;
      delete $scope.newItem.asset_reg_no;
      return;
    }
    $scope.newItem.id = asset.id;
    $scope.newItem.asset_reg_no = asset.asset_reg_no;
  });

}
```

Comment: Here the problem is, when I select the item the text box shows the id instead of text, am expecting the autocompleted text to be appear there.When I select my previous code, I will get result like this ``{
  "id": "1",
  "asset_reg_no": "AST1",
  "asset_name": "Omega Shopping Complex",
  "asset_type_id": "2",
  "description": "Shopping Complex in Calicut",
  "created_on": "2014-01-28 16:03:23",
  "asset_type_name": "Building"
}`` and I want to assign the ``id`` to one hidden textbox and ``asset_reg_no`` to another text.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zeljko/q8L6G/) is what you want

```
    function ctrl($scope){
        $scope.assets = [{"id":"1","asset_reg_no":"AST1","asset_name":"Omega Shopping Complex","asset_type_id":"2","description":"Shopping Complex in Calicut","created_on":"2014-01-28 16:03:23","asset_type_name":"Building"},{"id":"2","asset_reg_no":"AST2","asset_name":"Keedam Chicken Farm","asset_type_id":"2","description":"Chicken farm in Valivida","created_on":"2014-01-28 16:04:06","asset_type_name":"Building"}];

    $scope.newItem = {};
    $scope.$watch('customSelected', function(asset, oldAsset){
    $scope.newItem.id = asset.id;
    $scope.newItem.text = asset.asset_name;
      });

    }
```